# iOS returning from safari (or another app)

Tags: ios, view

My problem is the following: in my app, I need to switch to safari for a login; however, when the user is redirected to my app, I want a specific action to be executed. Is there a way to do that? ViewWillAppear doesn't work, since it's called only the first time the views shows up....

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register your iOS app to handle URL scheme 'foo', then invoke or have a link pointing to 'foo://my_custom_launch_action' from your website. When your app launches, you may read the [launch options](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidFinishLaunchingWithOptions%3a) and act accordingly.

I think the official Flickr app for iPhone implements this mechanism to authenticate users through Safari from outside the app.

Comment: To be honest I don't fully understand your answer (I would be glad if you could explain me how the "foo://my_custom_launch_action" url works), but it helped me to solve my problem: I just use the "- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application" method of the app delegate to check if the user is logged in when he comes back to the my app.

Comment: Glad it helped. This is what I meant anyway: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html